# How can I get the scrollbar to control the text region?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to scroll down the Text object the scroll bar sort of bounces back instead of actually scrolling

```py
memo_content = Text(edit_window,height = 4, width = 40)
memo_content.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E+W)
scroll_memo_content=Scrollbar(edit_window)
scroll_memo_content.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = N+S)
memo_content.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_memo_content.set)
```

The scroll bar has no control over the text field and when I drag it it snaps back to where it was meaning that the only way to scroll is by holding the up/down arrow and the cursor moving

Comment: Use [tkinter.scrolledtext](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root, height=25, width=50)

sb = Scrollbar(root)

text.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.configure(command=text.yview) # <- You missed this

sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text.pack()
```

You missed configuring the actual scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a scrollbar requires two steps:

1. You must configure the scrollbar to know which widget it is controlling. This is typically done by setting the `command` attribute of the scrollbar to be the `yview` command of a scrollable widget.
2. You must configure the window to be scrolled to know scrollbar needs to be updated when its position changes. This is typically done by setting the `yscrollcommand` or `xscrollcomand` of the widget to the `set` method of an appropriate scrollbar.

You are forgetting to do the first step.

Make the following change:

```
scroll_memo_content=Scrollbar(edit_window, command=memo_content.yview)
```